# Insert into query from form when date field is empty

Tags: ms-access, datetime, sql-insert, string

In MS Access, I have an unbound form with, among others, two fields with a format of "short date" so I can get the date picker to show (Access 2007).
On click of a button, the data is inserted into a table using this sql query in vba

```
strInsert = "INSERT INTO atbl_invoice (cust_id, inv_date, job_no, item_desc, job_desc, type, fday, reqday) " & _
            "VALUES(" & strCid & ", Date(),'" & Me.JobNo & "','" & Me.item_desc & "','" & Me.job_desc & "','" & Me.cboType & "','" & Me.fday & "','" & Me.reqday & "')"
```

fday and reqday in the table are time/date fields and are set to 'required=No'.

All goes fine if the two date fields on the form are filled in, but if either of them is left empty, I get a "set 1 fields to Nul due to a type conversion failure" error because it is trying to put an empty string into a date/time field.

Does any one know of a way that I can leave these fields blank and still have my insert query work?

THANKS for the help.
In case anyone is wondering, this is how I ended up doing it.

```
Dim strInsert0 As String
Dim strInsert1 As String
Dim strInsert2 As String
Dim strInsert3 As String
Dim strCid As String

strCid = Forms!frmCustomer!cid

strInsert0 = "INSERT INTO atbl_invoice (cust_id, inv_date, job_no, item_desc, job_desc, type) " & _
            "VALUES(" & strCid & ", Date(),'" & Me.JobNo & "','" & Me.item_desc & "','" & Me.job_desc & "'," & _
            "'" & Me.cboType & "')"

strInsert1 = "INSERT INTO atbl_invoice (cust_id, inv_date, job_no, item_desc, job_desc, type, fday) " & _
            "VALUES(" & strCid & ", Date(),'" & Me.JobNo & "','" & Me.item_desc & "','" & Me.job_desc & "'," & _
            "'" & Me.cboType & "','" & Me.fday & "')"

strInsert2 = "INSERT INTO atbl_invoice (cust_id, inv_date, job_no, item_desc, job_desc, type, reqday) " & _
            "VALUES(" & strCid & ", Date(),'" & Me.JobNo & "','" & Me.item_desc & "','" & Me.job_desc & "'," & _
            "'" & Me.cboType & "','" & Me.reqday & "')"

strInsert3 = "INSERT INTO atbl_invoice (cust_id, inv_date, job_no, item_desc, job_desc, type, fday, reqday) " & _
            "VALUES(" & strCid & ", Date(),'" & Me.JobNo & "','" & Me.item_desc & "','" & Me.job_desc & "'," & _
            "'" & Me.cboType & "','" & Me.fday & "','" & Me.reqday & "')"

If IsNull(Me.reqday) And Not IsNull(Me.fday) Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL strInsert1

ElseIf IsNull(Me.fday) And Not IsNull(Me.reqday) Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL strInsert2

ElseIf IsNull(Me.reqday) And IsNull(Me.fday) Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL strInsert0

Else: DoCmd.RunSQL strInsert3

End If
```

Having the two date fields, either of which could have been empty or not, complicated it a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but I believe you cannot store null values. If I were you, I would run an if statement to check if they are null. Check out this code below:

```
    if len(me.fday.value) > 0  and len(me.reqday.value) > 0 then
          strInsert = "INSERT INTO atbl_invoice (cust_id, inv_date, job_no, item_desc, job_desc, type, fday, reqday) " & _ "VALUES(" & strCid & ", Date(),'" & Me.JobNo & "','" & Me.item_desc & "','" & Me.job_desc & "','" & Me.cboType & "','" & Me.fday & "','" & Me.reqday & "')"
    else
        strInsert = "INSERT INTO atbl_invoice (cust_id, inv_date, job_no, item_desc, job_desc, type) " & _ "VALUES(" & strCid & ", Date(),'" & Me.JobNo & "','" & Me.item_desc & "','" & Me.job_desc & "','" & Me.cboType & "')"
    end if
```

See if this works, if it doesn't, comment on the answer and let me know.

Comment: I was hoping this wouldn't be the case as having two date fields means a much longer If statement, but if that is what is required I will have to bite the bullet.

Comment: I'm going with this answer although I will use a case select because I need to take into account if both are empty, If only one is empty, if only the other is empty, and if they are both full. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

In the sql string use the following query:

> insert into mytable (mydata) values (#01/01/2020#)

or

> insert into mytable (mydata) values (NULL)